# How to use or reference a Java project from a Grails project?

Tags: java, grails, compilation

I have a grails project that works normally. Lately, our team decided to put an extra feature in the app that was already implemented in a Java standalone app of our own. "So", I thought, "I only need to reference the standalone Java project in my workspace". So I did that - referenced my Java project from the Grails one and called the service from a Groovy class located in src/groovy. When I tried to run the web project I got a compilation error:

```
Error Compilation error: startup failed: 
unable to resolve class com.CycleManager
```

And it says that the error is the import line for the CycleManager class.

Why can't groovy find the referenced project? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to build your application? You need to make sure the classes or jar file containing the classes is on your classpath when you do your build.

Comment: Well, the standalone project is referenced. I'm not embedding a jar (at least not on purpose). Don't really know how grails builds referenced projects though. But, in STS, if I use Project -> Properties -> Build path -> Projects, and add a project, it is supposed to reference my project. Right?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because grails cannot see the jar/classes which is exposing the service. You need to include the jar(s) in your grails classpath(which is not in your workspace). This can be done by mentioning about the jar in the **BuildConfig.groovy** file of your grails application in dependencies section.

```
dependencies {
             // your jar name
    compile ("com.CycleManager")
}
```

This is the proper way to include the jars in your application.

P.S : Grails expects your jar to be in its ivy-cache. If it is not present in ivy-cache it will be pulled from your snapshots folder.

Comment: I am not using a jar (at least I don't think so). I'm referencing a project in my workspace. I absolutely have to use it as a jar?

Comment: I tried to replicate your situation and got the same problem. I don't think _grails_ will be able to see the projects which are referred through your ide (not sure about this).